# How can I select only certain values in an array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an array and I want to apply this transformation to only the 1st and 3rd of the value positions.

so values such as

```
( -0.23685953, -0.23685953,0.12831355 | 0.94160742, 0.67673782, 0.27031023)


 X = np.array([[-0.23685953,  0.04296864,  0.94160742],  
               [-0.23685953,  1.05043547,  0.67673782],
               [0.12831355,  0.16017461,  0.27031023]])
```

Transformation I want to apply

```
 x_np = np.asarray(X)
 np_minmax = (x_np - x_np.min()) / (x_np.max() - x_np.min())
```

Comment: Please define precisely `1st and 3rd of the value positions` and show your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to apply this transformation to 1st and 3rd columns.
You can achieve this by using MinMaxScaler from sklearn

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-0.23685953, 0.04296864, 0.94160742],
              [-0.23685953, 1.05043547, 0.67673782],
              [0.12831355, 0.16017461, 0.27031023]])
```

We apply min-max scaling for 0th and 2nd column only(0 based indexing)

```
scalar=MinMaxScaler()
scaled_columns=scalar.fit_transform(X[:,[0,2]])
```

Now we combine these transformed columns with non transformed middle comlumn using numpy's column stack function.

```
X=np.column_stack((scaled_columns[:,0],X[:,1],scaled_columns[:,1]))
print(X)


[[ 0.          0.04296864  1.        ]
 [ 0.          1.05043547  0.60543616]
 [ 1.          0.16017461  0.        ]]
```